# ASP.NET Identity, "Remember Me" and cookie timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my MVC Startup.Auth.cs file, there is this code:

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                        .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
                            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                            regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) =>
                                user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                            getUserIdCallback: (id) => (id.GetUserId<int>()))
                }
```

If I understand this correctly, the login cookie will expire in 30 minutes. Which means the user will be forced to log back in, in 30 minutes. If this is correct, what is the value of having the user select "Remember Me" on the login page if the login cookie expires in 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet of code you show does not have much to do with "Remember Me". `SecurityStampValidator` is actually checking if the created cookie is still valid against the user record in the database. And `validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)` defines the interval on how often to check the cookie against the database.

Cookie created by Identity framework contains data that is usually enough to use without having to go back to the database on every HTTP request, so to improve performance cookie is not checked with the DB on every request. But you can invalidate all user cookies by changing the `SecurityStamp` in the database. And this `SecurityStampValidator` checks for that. But if nothing is changed within 30 minutes after user is logged in, they will not be logged-out. Only the value of cookie will be updated, but the user will still be logged-in.

I hope this is more clear now.